# How to fill a character array using a loop with a text file in C

Tags: c

While working in a terminal, my goal is to scan in a text file through a character array as such:
./a.out < namelist.txt
and then print the txt to the screen with how many characters are in it.  The file can hold up to 8000 characters.  I'm trying to use a loop to fill the array up but I keep on only getting the first letter of the file.  Any idea how I can start this off?

```
const int MAX = 8000;
int input = 1;
int i = 0;
char text[MAX];
while(input != 0)
{
    scanf("%c", &text[i]);
    if(text[i] == '0')
        input = 0;
    i++;
}
printf("\n%s",text);

return 0;
```

Comment: Is the first character in the file `'0'`? What you *should* be checking is the return value from `scanf`. Asides: `MAX` should be `8001` and you should insert a string terminator with `text[i] = '\0'` after the loop ended. And check `i` for array overflow anyway.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

suggest replacing:

```
while(input != 0)
{
    scanf("%c", &text[i]);
    if(text[i] == '0')
        input = 0;
    i++;
}
```

with something similar to;

```
// avoid 'text' overflow and
// check that call to `scanf()` was successful
while( i < (MAX-1) && scanf( "%c", &text[i] ) == 1 )
{
    // step index to next position in the array: 'text[]'
    i++;
}
```

then, finally:

```
// teminate the 'text' string
text[ i ] = '\0';

// print number of characters and the actual text
// on separate lines
printf("\nNumber of Characters read: %d\n%s\n", i, text);
```